# Send integer value from text field in Flutter to Go backend

Tags: flutter

I am trying to send data of a Student to be added in SQL database by using Go. This is the code :

```
 final jsonbody = jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
                    "StudentId": idController.text,
                    "StudentName": snController.text,
                    "FatherName": fnController.text,
                    "MotherName": mnController.text,
                    "Cgpa": cgController.text,
                    "City": ctController.text
                  });
                  print(jsonbody);
                  final responseofAPI = await http.post(
                      Uri.parse(url),
                      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                      body: jsonbody);
                  print("Code -----> ${responseofAPI.statusCode}");

                  print(jsonDecode(responseofAPI.body));
                  print(responseofAPI.body);
```

And this is the response I am getting :

```
I/flutter (22041): {"StudentId":"84","StudentName":"Mukul","FatherName":"Mukesh","MotherName":"Swati","Cgpa":"7","City":"Kanpur"}
I/flutter (22041): Code -----> 400
E/flutter (22041): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
E/flutter (22041): 
E/flutter (22041): ^
```

I have to send the studentId and Cgpa as integer values thats the reason I think the error is coming from.It is now going as string.  How can I send integer value from Frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you commit that the string value from the controller is integer, you can convert the value to integer with int.parse("")

```
final jsonbody = jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
                        "StudentId": int.parse(idController.text),
                        "StudentName": snController.text,
                        "FatherName": fnController.text,
                        "MotherName": mnController.text,
                        "Cgpa": int.parse(cgController.text),
                        "City": ctController.text
                      });
                      print(jsonbody);
                      final responseofAPI = await http.post(
                          Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.19:8081/everyStudent'),
                          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                          body: jsonbody);
                      print("Code -----> ${responseofAPI.statusCode}");
    
                      print(jsonDecode(responseofAPI.body));
                      print(responseofAPI.body);
```

Comment: kindly, add a little information like what was the issue and how you have resolved.